# Executing a query within forall

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a set of queries that is present Queries.
Now i want to execute this by using forall in the way shown below:

```
open EX01_CURSOR;

LOOP
  FETCH EX01_CURSOR BULK COLLECT INTO Queries LIMIT 50000;
  EXIT WHEN Queries.COUNT = 0;
    FORALL i IN 1 .. Queries.count
    **execute immediate Queries(i).update_query;**
    commit;

END LOOP;

close EX01_CURSOR;
```

I want to execute my query within the forall block.
I'm getting compilation errors as shown below:

> DML statement without BULK In-BIND cannot be used inside FORALL

can somebody please help?

Comment: Please tag the language/technology. How are people supposed to help if they don't have any idea what they are looking at? Also please read this before posting any more to SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814535/getting-error-pls-00435-dml-statement-without-bulk-in-bind-cannot-be-used-insid

Answer (score 0):

`FORALL` isn't really a `LOOP` or iterator, but is a `BULK` `DML` operation.  It doesn't run an operation for each entry in the collection,  entry-by-entry, but runs one DML operation for all the entries in the collection.  You can't run `Dynamic SQL` in `BULK` and can't iterate.  To iterate and run the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, you will need use a `LOOP` (or to take another approach).

Here's an example.  It still uses `BULK COLLECT` to control commit size, but does the `Dynamic SQL` in a `FOR LOOP`.  (Note: not efficient to do this volume of Dynamic SQL.  Just an example keeping your original collection size)

Set up test data:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (
  TEST_ID NUMBER
);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE SELECT LEVEL
                       FROM DUAL
                       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 50001;
```

Initial Data:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE ORDER BY 1 DESC FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
TEST_ID  
50001           
50000           
49999           
49998           
49997
```

Then run the block.  This does not use `FORALL` `BULK DML`.  It uses a `FOR LOOP` instead:

```
DECLARE

  CURSOR EX01_CURSOR IS (
    SELECT 'UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET TEST_TABLE.TEST_ID = TEST_TABLE.TEST_ID + 100000 WHERE TEST_TABLE.TEST_ID = ' ||
           TEST_TABLE.TEST_ID AS UPDATE_QUERY
    FROM TEST_TABLE);

  TYPE EX01_CUR_TYPE IS TABLE OF EX01_CURSOR%ROWTYPE;
  QUERIES EX01_CUR_TYPE;

BEGIN
  QUERIES := EX01_CUR_TYPE();

  OPEN EX01_CURSOR;

  LOOP
    FETCH EX01_CURSOR BULK COLLECT INTO QUERIES LIMIT 50000;
    EXIT WHEN QUERIES.COUNT = 0;

    FOR UPDATE_POINTER IN 1..QUERIES.COUNT
    LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE QUERIES(UPDATE_POINTER).UPDATE_QUERY;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE EX01_CURSOR;
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE ORDER BY 1 DESC FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
TEST_ID  
150001   
150000   
149999   
149998   
149997
```